# What is this game with the missing heads from Nokia Gaming?

Tags: game-identification

I saw this game on [Tiktok](https://www.tiktok.com/@nokiagaming001/video/7129731954596973866) but couldn't find its name.

[image: Unknown Tiktok game]

Comment: It's a video made by a user called nokiagaming001—I assume it has nothing to do with the Finnish telecom company Nokia.